# Active record query for double many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app in which I have three models

1) Company

2) Car

3) Location

The relationship between my three models is, Company has many Cars and Each car has many locations:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :cars    
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :locations    
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Now I want to write two activerecord queries

1) To get all the locations of all the cars of a particular company in a single variable

2) To get the last location of all the cars of a particular company in a single variable

Can anyone help me in writing these queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd do something like `Company.with_name("Blabla Gmbh").cars.all_locations` after I create some [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: Can you help me to write scope for this ?

Comment: Not really. I'm not aware of your table columns. The link I sent you in my previous comment is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

from

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :cars    
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :locations    
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

to

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :cars
  has_many :locations, through: :cars    
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :locations    
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

1) To get all the locations of all the cars of a particular company in a single variable

`Company.where({...}).first.locations` , or with your scope
`Company.with_name("Blabla Gmbh").locations`

2) To get the last location of all the cars of a particular company in a single variable

`Company.with_name("Blabla Gmbh").locations.last`